# Upgrade to 21.04 - Graphic login problem + Fail to start Service for snap application ... livepattch

Tags: boot, upgrade, login, display-manager

I am not an advance user of Ubuntu, using an old HP Envy Dv7 laptop.  I am happy that finally I can upgrade my Ubuntu from 20.10 to 21.04 last night.  The installation runs smoothly.

Once my computer reboots， I try to start up Ubuntu with [Linux.5.11.0-17 generic] kernel and  receive the following problem：

/dev/sda6: clean, 1878532/24820052 files, 31081891/99293696 blocks
[FAILED] Failed to start Service for snap application canonical-livepath.canonical-livepatchd.

Then the computer did not proceed to logon screen, but stay fixed with a **black** screen.

To solve this problem, I restart Ubuntu 21.04 with [Linux.5.11.0-17 generic] in recovery mode.
I try to run clean, dpkg, fsck in the *recovery menu*, everything seems ok.

I also try to go to the root shell prompt to run:  sudo dpkg --configure -a

Then, I resume to continue to boot by exiting the recovery menu.

Then I arrived at the screen:

Ubuntu 21.04 jcylo2000-HP-ENVY-dv7-Notebook-PC tty1

jcylo2000-HP-ENVY-dv7-Notebook-PC login:

at the terminal login.  It seems that I cannot go to the graphical login (Wayland - GNOME interface).

Please give me some pointers to solve this problem.  I suspect it has to with the **Wayland / sddm / gdm** display manager.

Please help, thank you,  John

Comment: I seem to solve my own problem but starting the graphical login using the command:  sudo systemctl restart gdm.service

Comment: But when I reboot the machine, I will have problem load the graphic login screen.  I resort to login to tty1 then use the command sudo systemctl restart gdm.service.  Please help!!